# How to find the difference between 2 NaiveDateTimes?

Tags: datetime, rust, timestamp, rust-chrono

I am using [chrono](https://crates.io/crates/chrono). I have `now()` and some other `NaiveDateTime`. How can I find a difference between them?

```
let now = Utc::now().naive_utc();
let dt1 = get_my_naive_datetime();
```

Answer (score 7):

In more recent versions of `chrono` (at least as of 0.4.22, and likely earlier), you can simply subtract `NaiveDateTime`s:

```
println!("{:?}", dt1 - now);
```

The result is a [`Duration`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.Duration.html), which has methods to convert to whatever units you like, e.g. `(dt1 - now).num_days()`.

In older versions of `chrono`, you must use [`NaiveDateTime::signed_duration_since`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html#method.signed_duration_since):

```
println!("{:?}", dt1.signed_duration_since(now));
```

Comment: how to get that in days, hours, minutes?

Comment: @Kurama what's the question about? This method returns the `Duration` object which has all the methods you want, - to get days, hours and minutes. Just open that link and you'll see.

Comment: Or you can simply use subtraction to get a `Duration` from two `NaiveDateTime` instances: `now-dt1`

Comment: @Jmb which will yield another Duration. What will I do with it?