# How do I get Duration from two DateTime / NaiveDateTime?

Tags: rust

I'm using chrono crate

I've got date in `i64` and I can get `NaiveDateTime` with `NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp`

I have `Local::now()` current time and I can get `i64` with `.timestamp()`

But I still can't understand how to get `Duration` of `my_time - current_time` because it tells that Sub is not implemented if I try it like that

And if I get diff in i64 timestamps how to convert it into `Duration`?

e.g. I want something alike but sub is not implemented there

```
let uEnd = NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(end64, 0);
let dtEnd = uEnd.sub(Local::now());
```

Comment: As a side note, consider Rust's [naming conventions](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html). Local variable names should preferably be in snake_case.

Comment: Incidentally, `Sub` is used for something else in chrono's case (UTC offsets). You cannot subtract two instants and get a duration. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48312801/3650362)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two date-time types are not compatible, because `NaiveDateTime` lacks a time zone. In this case, since you obtained it using `NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp`, you can convert it to a `DateTime<Utc>` first, and then obtain the difference with `signed_duration_since`.

```
let now = Local::now();
let naive_dt = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2018, 3, 26).and_hms(10, 02, 0);
let other_dt = DateTime::<Utc>::from_utc(naive_dt, Utc);

let diff = now.signed_duration_since(other_dt);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b43ae67442f52dfd507bdb24cc906132&version=stable)

---

Future versions of `chrono` (after 0.4.1) will support subtracting as an alternative to calling `.signed_duration_since`, as long as both operands have the same time zone type. [PR #237](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/pull/237) Therefore, one will eventually be able to write this:

```
let diff = now.with_timezone(&Utc) - other_dt;
```